# Accessing field variables in Views 3.0

Tags: 7, views

Since the Documentation for Views 3.0 isn't out yet, does that mean that the way you access field variables is different from Views 2.0? That's because whenever I try the following code (from Views 2.0 docs: http://drupal.org/node/352970), all I get are errors:

```
<?php
    dsm(array_keys($fields));

    //ERROR message after placing it in views-view.tpl.php:
    Notice: Undefined variable: fields in include() (line 33 of D:\xampp\htdocs\foo\sites\all\themes\foofoo\views\views-view.tpl.php).
    Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in include() (line 33 of D:\xampp\htdocs\foo\sites\all\themes\foofoo\views\views-view.tpl.php).
?>
```

In my modules I have Devel and Theme Developer enabled so why isnt it working? I also rescan my template files like a boss and clear my cache like a disease but still nothing.

Comment: If you look at the top of the file you will see the availible variables. $fields is definitive not availible at this level, because it has multiple rows.

Comment: I got it. It's `print $fields['field_productshots']->content;`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
<?php
 dsm (array_keys(get_defined_vars())); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Drupal 7 `$fields` variable is undefined in the view template. Use $row:

```
//for id
$row->_field_data['id']['entity']->id
//for field_second_side
$row->_field_data['id']['entity']->field_second_side[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
```

Current field value is stored in `$output`.